# Flexbox justified grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I am triyng ot create same basic justified grid with flexbox. If I lay some images and applay flex wrap it looks like this:

```css
#wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.box {
  margin: 1px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="box"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x150" /></div>
  <div class="box"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x150" /></div>
  <div class="box"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x150" /></div>
  <div class="box"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" /></div>


</div>
```

This work well, but as soon as avalable width gets smaller images fall into new line (because of wrap obviously). I am wondering can this be made responsive so it keeps this layout regardless of available width? But it would need to be dynamic without applying individual classes to images with custom css.

Or this cannot be done without javascript?

Comment: Do you mean you want the container to not wrap images into new line, but continue to shrink the image sizes while keeping everything in one line?

Comment: Yes, something like justified galleries work, but I am affraid I will need javascript for that. Or at least defined row height.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle base on my understanding.
https://jsfiddle.net/m4j1e3tb/

The things I changed:

- each row would be its own flex container
- flex container would not wrap
- On the "box" which is the flex item, I added `flex-shrink: 1`, which tells the box to shrink when space "runs out"

```
.box {
  margin: 1px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

Edit: formatting. Sorry I'm still new to stackoverflow..